# Redux state is updating but field and value doesn't update accordingly. Have an extra undefined field with index when EDIT.USER.VALUE is dispatched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, onchange

I would like to update the state when I add multiple options in the field, so I **dispatch a EDIT.USER.VALUE**, it will keep tracking the changes.

But it appear an undefined field instead of updating the value for **role:[] and permission:[]** when I add an option into the field
[the application UI and redux store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqxaQ.png)

[when I add an option, it will appear undefine:0 in my redux store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am1W2.png)

[when I remove an option, it will appear undefine:0 with strikethrough in my redux store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUkUP.png)

What i would like to have is **show the value(selected option) in role:[] & permission:[] instead of having undefine:0**

Stack I use are **React, Redux, Material-UI  for multiple values**
and I'll provide my code base below

**Redux store:**

```
import { EDIT_USER_VALUE } from "../actions/user";

const initialState = {
    data: {},
    filter: "",
    user: {},
    userDetail: {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        fullname: "",
        email: "",
        role: [],
        permission: []
    },
    selectedUser: {},
    filters: {
        username: "",
        name: "",
    },
    create: {},
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    notify: false,
    noticeType: ""
};

export const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case EDIT_USER_VALUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                userDetail: {
                    ...state.userDetail,
                    [action.key]: action.value
                },
            };
            default:
                return state
}};
```

**React**

```
import {
    Box,
    Button,
    Typography
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { OneField } from "./UserSingleField";
import { SUBMIT_USER_PROFILE, EDIT_USER_VALUE } from "../../actions/user";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Autocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    headerContent: {
        display: 'flex',
        flex: 1,
        padding: "20px",
        marginBottom:"30px"
    },
    header: {
        display: 'flex',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
    },
    saveButton: {
        backgroundColor: "#719df4",
        display: "flex",
        fontSize: "14px",
        padding: "0",
    },
    edit: {
        display: "flex",
        flex: 1,
        marginBottom: "20px"
    },
    label: {
        alignItems: "center",
        display:"flex",
        flex: 1,
        fontSize: "16px",
        marginLeft: "20px",
    },
    fields: {
        display: "flex",
        flex: 2,
        marginRight: "20px"
    },
}));

const infoArr = [
    {
        label: "Username:",
        field: "name"
    },
    {
        label: "Name:",
        field: "fullname"
    },
    {
        label: "Email:",
        field: "email"
    }
 ]

const userRole = [
    { role: "VA" },
    { role: "VA 2" }
  ];
  
const userPermission = [
    { permission: "Channel 100001" }
  ];

export const UserEdit = ({ field }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const styles = useStyles();
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    const handleEditSave = (e) => {
        dispatch({ type: SUBMIT_USER_PROFILE });
    };  

    const handleFieldChange = (field) => (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        dispatch({ type: EDIT_USER_VALUE, key: field, value })
    }

    return (
    <>
        <Box>
            <Box className={styles.headerContent}>
                <Typography className={styles.header} variant="h4">User Profile</Typography>
                    <Button
                        color="primary"
                        variant="contained"
                        className={styles.saveButton}
                        onClick={handleEditSave}>
                        SAVE
                    </Button>
            </Box>

            {/* Username, Name, Email */}
            <Box >
            { infoArr.map(info => {
                return (
                <>
                    <Box className={styles.edit}>
                        <Box className={styles.label}>{info.label}</Box>
                        <OneField field={info.field} />
                    </Box>
                </> )})
            }
            </Box>
            
            <Box className={styles.edit}>
                <Box className={styles.label}>Roles: </Box>
                    <div className={styles.fields}>
                        <Autocomplete
                            multiple
                            fullWidth
                            options={userRole}
                            value={user.role}
                            onChange={handleFieldChange(field)}
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.role}
                            renderInput={(params) => (
                                <TextField
                                    {...params}
                                />
                            )}
                        />
                    </div>          
            </Box>

            <Box className={styles.edit}>
                <Box className={styles.label}>Permissions: </Box>
                    <div className={styles.fields}>
                        <Autocomplete
                            multiple
                            fullWidth
                            options={userPermission}
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.permission}
                            renderInput={(params) => (
                                <TextField
                                    {...params}
                                />
                            )}
                        />
                    </div>  
            </Box>
        </Box>
    </>)
}
```

**vibes/user.js**

```
const submitUserProfile = createVibes({
    type: SUBMIT_USER_PROFILE,
    async process({ getState, axios }, dispatch, done ) {
        const { userDetail } = getState().user;
    
        const userInfo = { 
            name: userDetail.name, 
            fullname: userDetail.fullname, 
            email: userDetail.email,
            system: 2,
            role: userDetail.role,
            permission: userDetail.permission
        }

        try {
            const userProfile = await axios.request({
                method: "post",
                url: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN + "/v1/api",
                data: {
                    query: `mutation addUser($form:UserInput){ addUser(input: $form){ id name } }`,
                    variables: {
                        form: userInfo
                    },
                },
            });

            if (userProfile && userProfile.status === 200) {
                dispatch({ type: SUBMIT_USER_PROFILE_SUCCESS,  
                    payload: {
                        notice: "User created successfully",
                    },
                });
                dispatch({ type: CLEAR_EDIT_SELECT_USER });
            }

        } catch (error) {
            if (error?.response) {
                dispatch({
                    type: SUBMIT_USER_PROFILE_FAIL,
                    payload: error.response?.data.errors[0]?.message,
                });
            } else {
                dispatch({
                    type: SUBMIT_USER_PROFILE_FAIL,
                    payload: typeof error === "string" ? error : error?.message,
                });
            }
        }
        done();
    },
});
```

At the end, english is not my native language so sorry for my terrible description.

Comment: have you tried doing `dispatch({ type: EDIT_USER_VALUE, payload: {key: field, value }})` (wrapping it on payload) then calling actions.payload on your reducer

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I haven't try it before. I'll try it now!

Comment: @IamL I have tried what you suggest. It doesn't appear undefined:0 anymore, but role and permission array didn't get update anything

Comment: I guess its just a matter of double checking whether you pass and read the correct data or no?

Comment: @IamL I hard coding the option data for user to choose from UI, this is what I hard coding in React file: ```const userRole = [{ role: "VA" }, { role: "VA 2" }]; const userPermission = [{ permission: "Channel 100001" }];```